# Electrum 2.0: non-BIP39/32 standardisation complicates matters immensely. Why?

Tags: electrum, thin-clients, bip32-hd-wallets, p2sh, mnemonic-seed

Electrum 2.0 has been causing me some frustration, insofar as it seems to be a non-standard implementation of BIP32/BIP39 (HD wallets, mnemonic seed, respectively). The wallet in question is a 2of2 multisig wallet (all P2SH), with the 2nd extended public key being created in *pybitcointools* using

`bip32_privtopub( bip32_master_key( sha256("a password") ) )`,

then imported into Electrum.

Given the 13 word seed, which itself is non standard since the last word is a checksum, it's proven impossible to export the `xpriv` key from Electrum.

How is a mnemonic seed converted to a BIP32 standard extended private key (given the client itself won't allow it)? : **EDIT1**: *with great difficulty, see my [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/36840/9382) below*

**(REFOCUSED) QUESTION**: *why does Electrum:

- stray from BIP0039?
- make exporting the master BIP32 private key *impossible?*
- return partially signed P2SH hex Txs which are malformed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an alternative way to extract the master extended private key (xprv): in the Electrum console, simply type this:

```
wallet.get_master_private_key('x/', gui.password_dialog())
```

Or for the master private key of a wallet created with Electrum 1.x, it's:

```
wallet.get_seed(gui.password_dialog())
```

#### Warning

Don't ever type your password or a private key into the console. In other words, don't do this:

```
wallet.get_seed('my-password')
```

Everything you type into the console is temporarily stored inside your wallet file *unencrypted* to make the command history feature (accessed via the up-arrow) work.

Comment: Where on earth did you find that?! Nice work!

Comment: Thanks! Someone on Bitcointalk was asking how to do this today, and I thought I'd dig around the Electrum source a bit to see if I could figure out a better way to do this before responding. Afterwards, it made sense to update this answer and get rid of the not-so-safe method that was here before.

Comment: `wallet.get_master_private_key('x/', None)` with no password FWIW, not `""`

Answer (score 3):

Thomas Voegtlin , the developer of Electrum explains the reasoning in the first 10 minutes of this interview. I think he also posted same thing to Bitcoin dev mailing list some time ago.

https://letstalkbitcoin.com/blog/post/epicenter-bitcoin-69-thomas-voegtlin-electrum-spv-wallets-and-bitcoin-aliases

His main point against BIP39 is that it doesn't include a version number, and the requirement of the word list dictionary in order to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Note: July 2017, Electrum v2.8.3... the command is now:

```
getmasterprivate()
```

The password dialog box will automagically pop up ;)

Comment: Hi HCP, welcome to Bitcoin.SE, and thanks for the update! We usually try to fully address the question in each answer, so, if you could add a little more explanation that would be great. If you just want to update a small part of an existing answer, you can also suggest an edit on it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this over at /r/Bitcoin:](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/2zym7e/how_to_export_master_private_key_xprv_on_electrum/), so apparently there's an exe to do this, but I'm not exactly game, since downloading the link got flagged by chrome.

It appears Electrum uses: `m/0/0` for wallet addresses and `m/1/0` for change addresses.

***EDIT:*** [A pull request has been submitted](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/pull/84) for code which extracts the root seed from the Electrum 2.0 seed phrase:

```
def electrumv2_extract_seed(words, password=''):
    """Takes Electrum v2.0 13 word mnemonic string and returns seed. Only works on English for now"""
    # clean-up unicode characters
    mnemonic = words[:]
    try:
        mnemonic = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', unicode(' '.join(words.lower().strip().split()))).encode('utf-8') # a string of 13 words
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(str(e))
    rootseed = pbkdf2.PBKDF2(str(mnemonic), str('electrum' + password), 2048,  macmodule=hmac, digestmodule=hashlib.sha512).read(64)
    return rootseed

def electrumv2_mnemonic_to_mprivkey(words, password=''):
    return bip32_master_key(electrumv2_extract_seed(words, password=''))
```

This is for use with [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) as `from bitcoin import *` in Python 2.7