# What BIP32 derivation path does Electrum use for Multisig?

Tags: electrum, bip32-hd-wallets, multi-signature

Same question as [What BIP32 derivation path does Electrum use?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36955/what-bip32-derivation-path-does-electrum-use)

but for multisig. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, I found out that Electrum uses following root derivation for normal and multisig wallets. For example:

- `root/0/0` for each cosigner. Example:

  - `m/44'/0'/0'` ==> shared root key (x)
  - `x/0/0` ==> address for first receiving multisig (derive in all cosigners shared keys. all 3 keys must be lexicographically ordered).
- some semi-compatible form of BIP45 for hardware wallets. Didn't test it but here's the code: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/lib/base_wizard.py#L220

refs:

[What BIP32 derivation path does Electrum use?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36955/what-bip32-derivation-path-does-electrum-use)

https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/2266

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1819380

Comment: I find that the purpose code is not present. See my answer. It is unclear what the m/44'/0'/0 generating the shared root key means in this answer. Starting with an xprv, a path of 0/0 generates the pubkeys used to construct the redeem scripts and the corresponding p2sh address used by Electrum for the first receiving address.

Comment: this is for hardware wallets only. for wallets that use electrum generated seeds x is just m for p2sh and m/1' for p2wsh

Answer (score 6):

Electrum uses BIP45.

`m / purpose' / cosigner_index / change / address_index`

Example for non-change of the first cosigner and first address: `m / 45' / 0 / 0 / 0`

See: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1634517.15
and
https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0045.mediawiki

Comment: I find the inclusion of the purpose code and cosigner index to not be present. See my answer below. Thus not BIP45.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a descriptor for a 2-of-3 created by Electrum.

Receive addresses:

```
sh(sortedmulti(2,XPUB_1/0/*,XPUB_2/0/*,XPUB_3/0/*))
```

Change addresses:

```
sh(sortedmulti(2,XPUB_1/1/*,XPUB_2/1/*,XPUB_3/1/*))
```

(Replace `XPUB_1`, `XPUB_2`, and `XPUB_3` with your three master public keys )

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me when using bip32gen from bip32utils to generate the public keys which are used in the transaction, starting from an xprv master key.

For each xprv master key of a cosigner, use 0/0 for the first receiving address, 0/1 for the second, 1/0 for the first change address, 1/1 for the second change address.

Then use the corresponding public key for each cosigner, sorted into lexicographic order, when constructing the redeem script, and generate the corresponding p2sh address for each address which will be generated by Electrum.

So far as I can tell, there are no purpose codes or cosigner index, as per BIP44 or BIP45. This is with Electrum 3.2.3.

refs: 
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1819380
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1816926.msg18101203#msg18101203

See this other stackexchange discussion: [What BIP32 derivation path does Electrum use?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36955/what-bip32-derivation-path-does-electrum-use/36956#36956)