# Derivation path for brute forcing "25th word" on a multisig wallet

Tags: multi-signature, wallet-recovery, passphrase

So I added a 25th word to my seed, forgot it, and am (after 6 months of on and off guessing) relegated to brute force (3rdIteration/btcrecover).

**Succinct question: what derivation path should I specify in the --bip32-path argument?**

- Hardware: Original Trezor
- Wallet creating software: Electrum in 2017
- Wallet setup: 2o3
- Wallet current software: Electrum in 2021
- the mpks are known

Electrum 2021 shows:

- script type, p2sh
- cosigner 1 [HW] trezor1 m/45'/0
- cosigner 2 [HW] trezor2 m/45'/0
- cosigner 3 unknown unknown.
- addresses, previous sends, balance (though maybe these are stored and not derived??)

I am trying to crack cosigner 2.

It is possible I copied the mpk from an old wallet so I am questioning the guarentee that m/45'/0 is the correct derivation path.  This is a multisig wallet. In electrum the walletinfo pane lists a derivation path of m/45'/0. Is this a derivation path I can use to crack my xpriv > xpub? Or is this misleading me and is instead a derivation path from xpub x 3 > multisig addresses (in this case my xpriv > xpub path could be anything)?

I've gone through most of the character spaces which I think my passphrase could occupy so I am hoping I am doing something wrong or the transition from 2017 to 2021 electrum has introduced a variation I have missed.

Any tips on what to double check? Notably [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51989/what-bip32-derivation-path-does-electrum-use-for-multisig?rq=1) post lists m/44'/0/

Comment: btcrecover command: python3 btcrecover.py --tokenlist tokenlist2.txt --mpk "xpub69XXX" --bip32-path "m/45'/0" --mnemonic "24 words verified to match my trezor --bip39"